# How can I reset my ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: bash, raspbian-lite

I accidentally replaced my `~/.bash_profile` with an empty file. My usually colored screen has turned black and white. (I'm running in command-line-mode with Raspbian Stretch Lite). How do I reset this file?

Comment: That file is not present by default on RPF Raspbian installs. Coloured prompt / listings etc is set in ~/.bashrc

Comment: My `pi@raspberrypi:~ $` used to be colored, now it's white...

Comment: The only thing I touched was added that file.

Comment: If you added that file, just add it again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy it from `/etc/skel/.profile`. You'll also find `.bashrc` in `/etc/skel`

Comment: Interesting. I will try this.

Comment: This may replace `.profile` but the question was about `/home/.bash_profile` (sic) which doesn't exist (neither does `~/.bash_profile`)

Comment: @Milliways whoops! I just corrected my question. I was a Linux noob back then